# What does the statement "x is a diagram of classical logics" mean?

Tags: logic, category-theory, quantum-calculus

From the Wikipedia entry on quantum [logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic)

> A more modern approach to the structure of quantum logic is to assume that it is a diagram – in the sense of category theory – of classical logics (see David Edwards).

What does the author mean by the statement *it is a diagram... of classical logics*?

What is a diagram?

I don't know category theory; I need to know only the gist of a meaning (precision isn't especially important). Accordingly, a plain-language answer would help the most.

Thank you,

-Hal

Comment: A category is a *directed graph* equipped with an associative *composition* operation of consecutive edges. A diagram is a kind of *subgraph* of it.

Comment: That sentence looks like garbled nonsense to me. Perhaps the author meant to say that a diagrammatic, category-theoretic approach (I'm thinking of the work of people like Abramsky and Coecke) to quantum logic is "more modern".

Comment: The author of the wikipedia article probably points to [this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00413704) (where category theory is introduced at page 19). I do not know the article and can't say if it is of value or not.